# Uploading JSON to firebase from dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, post, firebase-realtime-database

Having a puzzling problem posting JSON to firebase programatically:

Original JSON retreived from firebase:

`{'recipe1': {'abbie':2,'ben':0,'chris':1},'recipe2': {'abbie':1,'ben': 5,'chris':5}}`

I then convert it into a dataframe using pandas to manipulate the data, before turning it back into JSON. Here is where I'm getting stuck.

Convert dataframe to JSON:

`out = df.to_json()`

Result printed in terminal:

`{"recipe1":{"abbie":2,"ben":0,"chris":1},"recipe2":{"abbie":1,"ben":5,"chris":5}}`

```
firebase.post("/testupdate", out)
```

[image: POST data error]

Yet if I manually assign out to the same JSON structure:

```
out = {"recipe1":{"abbie":2,"ben":0,"chris":1},"recipe2":{"abbie":1,"ben":5,"chrisy":5}}
```

and post that,it works perfectly.

[image: Woking JSON post]

If anyone can help me out here it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I've just figured it out myself, assumed it would be a pretty simple fix.

Anyone else having this difficulty simply use:
     `out = df.to_dict()`
Instead of:

```
out = df.to_json()
```

When converting the dataframe.